# Attempted to Upgrade to Ubuntu 22, system won't start anymore

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded Ubuntu via the "Do you want to upgrade" prompt from Software Upgrader. 
Now this is the output when my system starts:

[image: img]

Typing on the keyboard does not work.

Comment: Reinstalling is the only way to go. But remember: Always backup before upgrading :)

Comment: Alternatively, boot into a Live environment and double-check the UUID of the partition where Ubuntu is installed. If the ID is different from what is recorded in `/etc/fstab` (which would be odd), then update the file system table file and reboot.

Comment: BTW what ubuntu version are u using?

Comment: By mention of Ubuntu v22; do you mean you're using Ubuntu Core 22 (the *year* format products are different to those using *year.month* format, ie. upgrading 20 to 22 differs when contrasted to a 20.04 to 22.04 upgrade; as no user app upgrades when 20 upgrades to 22 unlike 20.04 to 22.04 where all upgrade - so details matter!)

Comment: @matigo I agree this system is likely recoverable, but as this is happening at the initrams, editing fstab likely won't help.

Comment: Are you able to get back to grub and get the system running by selecting an alternative menu option?   What hardware are you running on?  (I wonder if there is a problem with a module needed to see your disk?)   Also - and I have no idea what this will produce but it won't damage your system - if you type "blkid<enter>" at the (initramfs) prompt what does it say? https://boxmatrix.info/wiki/BusyBox-Commands implies it should list the unique ID's of the block devices the system is aware of.

Comment: Details: I'm upgrading from 20.04 stable to 22.04 (or 22.10 whichever one is the default path). I didn't backup before upgrading so recovering the data would be excellent! I have a PCI SSD with dual boot partitioning using a modified Grub bootloader config. I remember getting the disk mounted at boot was a challenge, I think that's why I avoided the upgrade for so long.

Comment: Grub config is: https://i.imgur.com/ePWW0Xy.jpeg

Comment: Selecting different boot options from the Advanced Ubuntu boot menu results in the same issue

Comment: I was able to recover with use of ChatGPT. I chroot'd into the partition via the Try Ubuntu on my installer USB and ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`

From there, I had to do some more repairs since I had borked the upgrade, but the system works well enough for now.

Answer (score -1):

Restart the computer by shutting the power and then turn it on. When grub menu entry comes go to advance entries option and select the second option in recovery mode. It would let to the Ubuntu environment. after system starts up, use the terminal to fix broken packages

Sudo apt -f install

Sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.xx.xx.0-xx linux-image-5.xx.xx.o-xx

put the kernel numbers related to your upgraded kernel that caused the problem.

Sudo apt update

Sudo apt upgrade

It solved for me when my system behaved like that a year ago. Computer may need to be restarted a couple of times.